# How to install PhpStorm in Ubuntu 14.04 LTS?

Tags: software-installation, wine

I have a `JetBrains PhpStorm 7.1` and I want to install it in Ubuntu 14.04 so I installed `wine` for windows compatibility and I run `PhpStorm-7.1.exe` then it was successfully installed (I guess). But when I run the installed `PhpStorm` it gives me an error it says

> Failed to create JVM: error code -1

How can I fix this?

Comment: Is it 32 bit or 64 bit?

Comment: Is there a reason why you don't use the native linux version? PHPStorm is Java, it runs everywhere!

Comment: @NitishDhar It's 64 bit.

Comment: @Nemo64 I'm new to linux sir so i'm not fully aware of that.

Comment: Yeah just get it for ubuntu and don't use the windows one via wine.. if you still get the issue in the linux one then take a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14577663/eclipse-failed-to-create-the-java-virtual-machine

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Instructions here: https://web.archive.org/web/20161207101644/http://sysads.co.uk:80/2014/08/08/install-phpstorm-7-on-ubuntu-14-04/

**Please note that PhpStorm is not FREE, this is a 30-day trial!**

### Install dependencies

```
sudo apt-get purge openjdk*
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install oracle-java8-installer oracle-java8-set-default
```

### Install PhpStorm

```
wget http://download-cf.jetbrains.com/webide/PhpStorm-2017.1.4.tar.gz
tar -xvf PhpStorm-2017.1.4.tar.gz
cd PhpStorm-171.4694.2/bin/
./phpstorm.sh
```

Answer (score 4):

JetBrains are publishing their entire IDE portfolio as snaps, including PHPStorm. Snaps work on all supported versions of Ubuntu, including 14.04. Some of the advantages of the JetBrains snaps are that they are always up to date, will automatically stay updated and are very easy to install.

Install PHPStorm on Ubuntu 14.04:

```
sudo apt install snapd
sudo snap install phpstorm --classic
```

Comment: not sure why --classic option in this case ? Anyway should be considered as best answer now !

Comment: You can also use this method to install previous versions (i.e. if you need to drop back to the perpertual fallback license version). You just need to set the appropriate channel: `snap install phpstorm --channel=2019.3/stable --classic`

Comment: `--classic` is needed because this snap was built that way and "may
       perform arbitrary system changes outside of the security sandbox that snaps are usually
       confined to"

Answer (score 3):

### Install dependencies

```
sudo apt-get purge openjdk*
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install oracle-java7-installer oracle-java7-set-default
```

### Install PhpStorm

```
wget http://download-cf.jetbrains.com/webide/PhpStorm-7.1.3.tar.gz
tar -xvf PhpStorm-7.1.3.tar.gz
cd PhpStorm-133.982/bin
./phpstorm.sh
```

Comment: This should be updated to use the [oracle-java-8-installer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25731092/1269037).

Answer (score 1):

For new versions:

```
sudo apt-get purge openjdk*
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install oracle-java8-installer

wget http://download-cf.jetbrains.com/webide/PhpStorm-2016.2.tar.gz
tar -xvf PhpStorm-2016.2.tar.gz
cd PhpStorm-145.258.2/bin
./phpstorm.sh
```

note: if the link is broken try a higher version, current version is 2 as of July 2016. So next version will be `PhpStorm-2016.3.tar.gz`. And of course make sure that you cd into the right version `cd PhpStorm-xxxx/bin`

Answer (score -1):

Install dependencies

```
sudo apt-get purge openjdk*
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install oracle-java8-installer
```

Latest version till July, 29

```
wget http://download-cf.jetbrains.com/webide/PhpStorm-2016.2.tar.gz
tar -xvf PhpStorm-2016.2.tar.gz
cd PhpStorm-162.1121.38/bin
./phpstorm.sh
```

Answer (score -1):

*If you have java sdk installed (Like Oracle JDK 7/8 or Open JDK 7/8), skip this step and proceed to #3*

1. Open Terminal (<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>)
2. Install Open JDK 8

Note:
*it is recommended to use Oracle JDK, but Open JDK 8 will do (I am using it now, as well as with my IntelliJ Idea for Java)*

```
$ sudo apt-get install openjdk-8
```

(enter SUDO password)

3. You may use the latest version of PHP Storm:

- Download latest PHP Storm for Linux

  ```
  wget https://download-cf.jetbrains.com/webide/PhpStorm-2016.2.2.tar.gz**
  ```
- Extract downloaded tar.gz file

  ```
  tar -xvf PhpStorm-2016.2.2.tar.gz
  ```
- Navigate to bin's folder where phpstorm shell script is located

  ```
  cd PhpStorm-162.2380.11/bin/
  ```
- Run shell script

  ```
  ./phpstorm.sh
  ```

Good Luck!

Answer (score -1):

**Previous links are broken because now is required `https`**. **The links with `http` are dead!**

Up to this moment, the latest PHPStorm could be found here:

https://download-cf.jetbrains.com/webide/PhpStorm-2017.2.2.tar.gz

Answer (score -1):

similar script for install or update(auto) jetbrains products like phpstorm, webstorm, IntelliJ Idea and other. + dependencies + non latin hotkeys fixes
https://gist.github.com/zabidok/8418c4f679741f585ac9ce90b16fb8a5

Answer (score -1):

just make sure you pick up the latest phpStorm version. 
January 27th 2018 - version PhpStorm-2017.3.3.tar.gz

```
sudo apt-get purge openjdk*
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install oracle-java8-installer
wget https://download-cf.jetbrains.com/webide/PhpStorm-2017.3.3.tar.gz

tar -xvf PhpStorm-2017.3.3.tar.gz
cd PhpStorm-173.4301.34/bin
./phpstorm.sh
```

Comment: Please don't add an answer that is essentially the same as [another one](https://askubuntu.com/a/801254/616451). Instead, update the other answer to the newer version of PhpStorm by [editing it](https://askubuntu.com/posts/801254/edit). Once you're done editing it, please delete this answer.