# How to install phpstorm and IntelliJ with the package manager on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: apt, package-management, intellij

About phpstorm all i found was this: [How to install PhpStorm in Ubuntu 14.04 LTS?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/474151/how-to-install-phpstorm-in-ubuntu-14-04-lts)

But since wget links are forbidden now, this dont work. Anyone have an update on this?

About intelliJ I found this: [Setup and install IntelliJ with JDK](https://askubuntu.com/questions/272314/setup-and-install-intellij-with-jdk)

But this is not with the package manager. Is it still possible to do this?

Comment: I don't think that Netbeans offers PPA for their programs and I also don't see any PPA for phpstorm and IntelliJ, you need to download and upgrade these applications manually.

Comment: Yea, I dowloaded the tar.gz files and installed them like such instead.

Answer (score 0):

What worked quite nice for me (Ubuntu 16.04 and PhpStorm 2017.3.2) was installing PhpStorm as a Snap package:

`sudo snap install phpstorm --classic`

as mentioned on PhpStorm's [official download page](https://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/download/#section=linux).

Some more useful info about Snaps, you can [find here](https://www.howtogeek.com/252047/how-to-install-and-manage-snap-packages-on-ubuntu-16.04-lts/).